# need help making POST call with Alamofire to retrive XML

Tags: xml, swift, xcode, post, alamofire

I have found several examples online for how to use Alamofire to get results and JSON and create a JSON object...I'm trying to get the results of an API that returns XML (which I'll parse later) but can't find any good examples that work.  I'm using Xcode 8.0, Swift 3, and the most current version of Alamofire (Sep 2016, maybe ver 4.0?)

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

var first_name = ""
var last_name = ""

var URLString = "https://api-equitywerks.rhcloud.com/api/read_ls.xml"

let parameters = [
    "Firstname":  "\(first_name)",
    "Lastname": "\(last_name)", ];

func test() {
   Alamofire.request(URLString,
              method: .post,
              parameters: parameters,
              encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
         .responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

switch(response.result) {
case .success(_):
    if let data = response.result.value{
        print(response.result.value)
        print(data)
    }
    break

case .failure(_):
    print(response.result.error)
    break

    }
   }
}
```

I think I want to replace the .responseJSON chained call with .response, but when I try to do that I get errors.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't call `responseJSON` to get the xml response. You need to use `responseString` to get the raw string or `responseData` to get raw data.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class TestAlamofireXML: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        getData()
    }

    func getData() {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api-equitywerks.rhcloud.com/api/read_ls.xml", parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: nil)
            .validate()
            .responseString {
                (response) in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let value):
                    print(value)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
    }
}
```